# use i3 tiling window manager in RHEL 5

Tags: window-manager, rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux, rhel-5

For some time I have been using the [i3 tiling window manager](http://i3wm.org/) in Ubuntu. However at my new company we use RHEL5. I would dearly love to port over all my configs but Im having some trouble...

An initial (naive) approach seems that a simple `yum install i3` yields no results for i3.

I then used some additional rpm repos by following instructions to add the [EPEL RPM Repositories](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#How_can_I_install_the_packages_from_the_EPEL_software_repository) but it seems i3 is only bundled for RHEL >= 6. Damn.

I'm fairly sure that this must be possible but I'm pretty new to the Redhat scene and am not sure how to approach this problem. Any pointers would be gratefully received!

Comment: I haven't tried but assuming that you have all the prerequisite packages, you can try building it from source. On RHL5, install build tools: ```yum install @development-tools```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I remotely used i3 and my normal dev tools from an ubuntu instance using ssh and sshfs to access the RHEL box files